# win 10 WinPython Script import xlwings get errors

Tags: python, xlwings, comtypes

1. Python and xlwings in same folder.  comtypes folder in xlwings folder
2. can't find module named 'com types'

The xlwings documentation says to install with pip.  This puts xlwings in the C:\Python27 folder.  WinPython ends up in the Downloads/WinPython-64bit-3.4.4-3Qtr5/  (1.37GB, btw)  moved the xlwings to the WinPython installed folder.

This is way too difficult.  Is there a straightforward way to set all this up so I can run a python script and get import xlwings as xw to work?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would work better:

- click on the "WinPython Command Prompt" icon of your WinPython distribution
- in the opening DOS windows, type:

> pip install xlwings

Comment: WORKED!  so simple.  Would it have been too difficult to mention that in the documentation?  Appreciate the help.